# Magnetic field of magnetic screwdriver?

Tags: electromagnetism, everyday-life

I wanted to know what is the typical strength of the magnetic field generated by the tip of a magnetic screwdriver, but couldn't find it anywhere on the manufacturers' webpages.

So I was wondering, is it possible to estimate it from the sort of objects that a magnetic screwdriver can pick up?

Comment: Well, it varies all over the map, from screwdrivers that can hardly hold a screw to ones that make the screw jump up an inch.  I would guess that the stronger ones have a ferrite magnet embedded in the handle, if that helps much.  Or you can weigh a screw and see how close the screwdriver must get to lift it.

Comment: It is actually surprisingly difficult to generate reliable and consistent strength in permanent magnets, so for most purposes people don't try. They just set some minimum operation test (...picks up a 1 gram test object from 5 mm distance...) to use for quality control and leave it at that. They may very well *not know* the field strength, and that doesn't bother them. If you care get (or build, they're pretty simple) a Hall probe and measure it as best you can.

Comment: Experiment: Get a magnetized screw driver and hold it near the magnetometer in your phone (assuming you have one). That should give you an idea of strength.

Comment: I like Dirk's idea of the phone magnetometer (although you may have to take measurments at different distances and then fit a dipole to it). For a rough idea, you can compare to similar size rare earth magnets, which typically generate fields of 1T at their surface. My feeling is that most magnetized tools will come in at, at most, around 0.1T. That's not a bad thing, by the way. A 1T magnet likes to attract an awful lot of magnetic dust and debris and is quite hard to keep clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. You can estimate by experimenting and playing with [a magnet calculator](https://www.kjmagnetics.com/calculator.asp) until the pull force numbers match up.